# How prove this $a^{km^n}\equiv 1\pmod{m^{n+1}}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,k,m,n$ be positive integers,if such
$$\color{red}{a^k\equiv 1\pmod m}$$
show that
$$\color{blue}{a^{km^n}\equiv 1\pmod{m^{n+1}}}$$

Let $a^k=mq+1$,then
$$a^{km^n}=(mq+1)^{m^n}=1+m^{n+1}q+\binom{m^{n}}{2}(mq)^2+\cdots$$
Feel about can be solved?In fact
$$m^{n+1}|\binom{m^n}{k}(mq)^k,k\ge 1?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that if $b \equiv 1 \pmod{m^{t}}$, for $t \ge 1$, then $b^{m} \equiv 1 \pmod{m^{t+1}}$.

To prove this, note, as you have done, that $b = 1 + m^{t} s$ for some $s$, so that  we have
$$
b^{m} = (1 + m^{t} s)^{m} = 1 + m m^{t} s +  \dots + \binom{m}{i} m^{t i} s^{i} + \dots
$$

Clearly the term $m m^{t} s$ is divisible by $m^{t+1}$, and so are the terms $m^{t i}$, for $i \ge 2$, as $t i \ge 2 t \ge t + 1$.